# Merge videos and images using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile one .webm file that contains this:

1. 10 seconds showing image1.jpg
2. Show a movie (an .mp4 file), which lasts about 20 seconds
3. 10 seconds showing image2.jpg
4. 10 seconds showing image3.jpg

I was unable to find out how/if the concatenate functionality of ffmpeg could do such a thing. Any clues?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat).

## Without audio

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image1.jpg \
-i video.mp4 \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image2.jpg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image3.jpg \
-filter_complex "[0][1][2][3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0" out.mp4
```

- Match `-framerate` with frame rate from `video.mp4`.

## With audio

If there is audio in `video.mp4` you'll need to provide audio for the images as well for it to be able to concatenate. Example of generating silence:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image1.jpg \
-i video.mp4 \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image2.jpg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i image3.jpg \
-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][4:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][4:a][3:v][4:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1" out.mp4
```

- Match `channel_layout` with audio channel layout (stereo, mono, 5.1, etc) from `video.mp4`.
- Match `sample_rate` with audio sample rate from `video.mp4`.
- No need to match the `-t` duration from `anullsrc` with any associated video input: the concat filter will automatically pad it to match video duration.

Comment: how can we add fade out effect to the first image and fade in effect to the second image in ffmpeg

Comment: As far as I remember this uses a lot of memory during execution. I used to split the task into creating the short clips from images one by one and then  concatenating them separately.

Comment: For future readers, `n` should be changed to the number of inputs minus 1

Comment: `n` is the number of segments to be concatenated. If both video and audio are being concatenated the video/audio pair is considered a segment. The *With audio* example in the answer has 4 video inputs and 4 audio inputs that create 4 pairs of segments, so `n=4`.

Comment: Can someone explain what's going on with that `-filter_complex`