# ffmpeg images to video with different start times and durations

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, php, exec

I've recently learned of FFMPEG's existence and I am trying to use it on my wordpress site.

On the site I am working on a html/php/js form page that lets users upload pictures, and set when the image shows and for how long.

Right now the code I have is only showing one image for the entire video.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['button'])) { 
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -t '.$cap_1.' -i /myurl/beach-1866431.jpg -t '.$cap_2.' -i /myurl/orlando-1104481-1.jpg -filter_complex "scale=1280:-2" -i /myurl/audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -y /myurl/'.$v_title.'.mp4 2>&1');
 } ?>
```

I tried setting "-t" for the duration with my php variables but nothing changes and I cant figure out what to use for the start time of each image.

Also, when writing shell_exec commands, instead of it all being on one line, is there a way to write working command code in php files with line breaks? For example -

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['button'])) { 
    echo shell_exec('ffmpeg -t '.$cap_1.' -i /myurl/beach-1866431.jpg 
    -t '.$cap_2.' -i /myurl/orlando-1104481-1.jpg 
    -filter_complex "scale=1280:-2" 
    -i /myurl/audio.mp3 
    -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -y /myurl/'.$v_title.'.mp4 2>&1');
         } ?>
```

**EDIT**

So far the concat text file seems to work, however I do not know how to set the start times for each image ---

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file /path/beach-1866431.jpg
duration 3
file /path/orlando-1104481-1.jpg
duration 5
file /path/beach-1866431.jpg
```

And ffmpeg command -

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i /path/file.txt -filter_complex "scale=1280:-2" -i /path/audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -y /path/'.$v_title.'.mp4 2>&1');
```

**EDIT 2**

Using the concat method suggested, my code now looks like this --

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['button'])) { 
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i goldmetal.jpg \
-i 3251.mp3 \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i cash-register-1885558.jpg \
-loop 1 -framerate 24 -t 10 -i ice-1915849.jpg \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:a][2:v][3:v]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 /path/'.$v_title.'.mp4 2>&1');
 } ?>
```

But I'm getting this error --

```
**Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][1:a][2:v][3:v]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.**
```

**EDIT 3**

I almost got it working as needed, using 2 commands, one for the images and fade, the other to combine the audio. The only issue I'm having is changing the time each image shows up. --

```
echo shell_exec('ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i '.$thepath .'/'.$v_pix1.' \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ' .$thepath . '/cash-register-1885558.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ' .$thepath . '/ice-1915849.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i '.$thepath .'/'.$v_pix1.' \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i ' .$thepath . '/ice-1915849.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9,setsar=sar=300/300[v0]; \
 [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9,setsar=sar=300/300[v1]; \
 [2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9,setsar=sar=300/300[v2]; \
 [3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9,setsar=sar=300/300[v3]; \
 [4:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9,setsar=sar=300/300[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -y '.$thepath .'/fadeout.mp4 2>&1');


echo shell_exec('ffmpeg \
-i '.$thepath .'/fadeout.mp4 \
-i '.$thepath .'/3251.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:a:0] concat=n=1:v=1:a=1 [vout] [aout]" -map "[vout]" -map "[aout]" -c:v libx264 -r 1 -y '.$thepath .'/mergetest.mp4 2>&1');
```

Comment: Your question is essentially three questions: 1) how do I concatenate images with `ffmpeg`?, 2) how do I implement the command in a PHP script, and 3) how do I add line breaks in the command in the PHP script? Lots of `ffmpeg` concat answers on this site ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43958846/1109017)). As for PHP, you should get the `ffmpeg` command working in cli first before you attempt to script it.

Comment: Is `3251.mp3` supposed to play during a specific image being displayed, or during the whole video? Since you introduced audio, all other segments need audio as well, and likewise each audio segment needs a corresponding video segment. So unless `3251.mp3` is playing during the whole video you need to generate silent audio for each image, and generate or provide a corresponding video segment for `3251.mp3`. See the example link for anullsrc to make silent audio.

Comment: The .mp3 audio is suppose to play during the whole video (without looping) @LordNeckbeard

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I tried following your example exactly and I am getting this error -- Stream specifier ':v' in filtergraph description [0:v][4:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][4:a][3:v][4:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 matches no streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the `ffmpeg` specific questions in your broad multi-question.

This example will take images of any arbitrary size, fit them into a 1280x720 box, fade between images, and play the audio at the same time. The video will end whenever the images or audio ends: whichever is shortest.

```
ffmpeg \
-i audio1.mp3 \
-i audio2.wav \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i image1.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i image2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i image3.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [4:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a];
 [v1][v2][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: thanks, I've managed to do that in my updated code though. What I'm having a problem with is also setting the time at which each image is suppose to appear.

Comment: @Rich This command does it all in one command instead of multiple commands. To control image duration change the appropriate `-t` value (don't forget to also adjust the fade values).

Comment: I dont mean the duration though. For instance my audio clip is 25 seconds, and I want picture 1 to show when at the 6 second mark of the clip, and picture 2 at the 12th second or so, etc. @lordneckbeard

Comment: @Rich I didn't get that is what you wanted from your question. So, to clarify, you want the *duration of each image = audio duration/number of images*?

Comment: no... what i have is a form that will let users upload photos and speech audio. On that form, for each picture they upload, there is input fields to enter 1. at what time in the video does the picture show 2. and for how long does the picture show for.... so the only thing I'm missing right now is number 1. The video lengths will all be based on the audio the user uses.

Comment: @Rich That can be controlled via `-t`. For example, image1 always starts at 0, image2 starts at 6 seconds, image3 is that last image and starts at 14 seconds until end of audio, then: `-loop 1 -t 6 -i image0 -loop 1 -t 8 -i image1 -loop 1 -i image3`.

Comment: I get what you are saying but I was looking for some more control than that. Simply setting a time for it to appear, like itsoffset or ss ? Im trying to make an online video editor with timeline editing similar to after effects, etc., using php, js, html5, and ffmpeg. So all I need to figure is how to let users set the time so that when I code the UI I can create a visual "timeline" for them to edit.

Comment: @Rich There are no practical methods to do so. `ffmpeg` isn't an editor. Perhaps `melt` will be a better choice for you. That being said, simple arithmetic in your script will allow you to come up with the proper `-t` values when a user enters the desired duration values.

Comment: @lordneckbead im not sure what melt is though

Comment: @Rich It's a command-line editor from [MLT](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/).

Comment: Im trying to modify my code to add another audio file as background music, any ideas? @lordneckbeard

Comment: i tried the updated code but im seeing this error -- `Invalid file index 4 in filtergraph description`